# JSON response data into swift objects [ObjectMapper]

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

Can you guys help me create swift objects of using ObjectMapper of following JSON data?

```
[{
    "location": "Toronto, Canada",    
    "three_day_forecast": [
        { 
            "conditions": "Partly cloudy",
            "day" : "Monday",
            "temperature": 20 
        },
        { 
            "conditions": "Showers",
            "day" : "Tuesday",
            "temperature": 22 
        },
        { 
            "conditions": "Sunny",
            "day" : "Wednesday",
            "temperature": 28 
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: [generated model](https://gist.github.com/romainmenke/3d2b7a0ade82ade9395c15fe08353e32)

Comment: @appzYourLife Structs don't allow attributes of type Self. So classes are better to represent JSON where that might happen. A failable init is hard to generalise. Some people want only the objects with complete data, others don't mind incomplete objects.

Comment: Did that code help you out?

Comment: What exactly do you want to access in this JSON?

Comment: Thanks @RMenke , That did help me sort out my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce a lot of boilerplate code by using [`BetterMappable`](https://github.com/PhonePe/BetterMappable) which is written over ObjectMapper using PropertyWrappers. You need to be on Swift 5.1 to use it.

Comment: Wow, I was finding a solution like this so that it reduces lots of boilerplate code. Thanks @Srikanth

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `ObjectMapper`:

```
import ObjectMapper

struct WeatherForecast: Mappable {
    var location = ""
    var threeDayForecast = [DailyForecast]()

    init?(_ map: Map) {
        // Validate your JSON here: check for required properties, etc
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        location            <- map["location"]
        threeDayForecast    <- map["three_day_forecast"]
    }
}

struct DailyForecast: Mappable {
    var conditions = ""
    var day = ""
    var temperature = 0

    init?(_ map: Map) {
        // Validate your JSON here: check for required properties, etc
    }

    mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
        conditions      <- map["conditions"]
        day             <- map["day"]
        temperature     <- map["temperature"]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// data is whatever you get back from the web request
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
let forecasts = Mapper<WeatherForecast>().mapArray(json)
```